# removing alert causes the system to not work

Tags: javascript

removing alert causes the system to not work. This issue was raised here

```
response = exchange.load_response();
// alert(response);
document.getElementById(exchange.get_output()).innerHTML = response;
// alert(response);
setTimeout('do_branding()',3000);
```

but I don't see how it was resolved

Comment: You probably have a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) somewhere, which the alert gets rid of because it waits for you to click the button.

Comment: Please explain what is issue your facing? You can't just use someone else solution to your problem. Your problem might be different, show us your code.

Comment: He seemed to have the exact same problem which is why I thought his solution would work for me.

Comment: [Close - too localized.  Final comment by OP shows a 'too specific' thing.

Comment: Your question cannot be properly solved because you are using unknown home made library that nobody has any idea what it does. The best someone can come up with is a hack, which will inevitably just cause another problem in the future

Comment: I get the need for info to help and I generally don't mind sharing code but I think adding more to this particular question would have confused or distracted people trying to help. Also, I knew that nothing in the `exchange` object was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems to be a race condition... `setTimeout` won't solve it since it doesn't wait with the rest of the JS, it just makes the call after the amount of time you tell it to...

You should either use a callback (this solves the problem completely) OR if that is not possible and you really want to solve the race condition by waiting then there are several ways to implement that `sleep` function - see for a callback-based example http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2005/10/28/put-javascript-to-sleep/

Comment: Thank you, I'm looking at that now

Comment: @Esailija My answer was before the OP posted the code! The problem with busy while loop is described explicitly in the first link provided (added a hint), the second link shows a different way (no busy waiting) and with jQuery `.delay` you are right (removed it)... one point though: when downvoting please always leave a comment with an explanation...

Comment: @Esailija without code and with the claim that `setTimeout` doesn't work for him that are (although not good!) options... the second link is actually pointing to a callback-based solution BTW...

Comment: Hey, I don't think I understanding when down voting is appropriate because the code I posted was the relevent code for my problem

Comment: thanks for the tip on race condition. I re-arranged my code and all is well.

Comment: @ThapsMagne you are welcome :-) please don't forget to mark as accepted any answer that helped (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: What I found, in my case, was that the code snippet I posted was in an `if` statement followed by a duplicate code block having different values in the exchange object. This second code block needed to be in a function and the function called by setTimeout. Problem solved. Thanks again.